# Can probability generating function diverge in 1?

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Let X be a discrete random variable taking value in Z>=0 and G(t)=E(t^X) be it's PHF.

It's true that left limit of G in 1 is equal to 1 , i.e.

lim G(t)=1   (t -> 1 from the left)

But is there an example in which the value of G(1) is not defined ?

Comment: If you define $G(t)=E[t^X]$ then $G(1)=E[1^X]=E[1]=1$. Or even more explicitly, $G(1)=\sum_k P(X=k)\cdot 1^k=\sum_k P(X=k)=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So why did wiki say only about left limit? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function

Comment: Apparently, because the right limit does not necessarily exist. Note that it is unrelated to value of the function **at** the point.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can you bring me an example?

Comment: I guess $G(t)={2\over\pi}\arcsin t$ would do.